# How can you generate test logs for functional tests on SoapUI?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, soapui

Are there any plugins available for this? Does SoapUI offer plugins/addins anyway?

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you are asking.

SoapUI generates a soapui.log by default in the current working directory. Basic information is available in the official [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/10-tips-for-the-soapui-beginner.html), under the heading "Tip 7) Read the Log".

As for plugins: yes there are plugins available, and described in the official [documentation](http://readyapi.smartbear.com/dev/start) as well.

Update:
If you are after logs of all the calls you made, then you need to launch the test runner with the -a or -A switch. As always official documentation is available for launching from the [GUI](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-soapui/launch-runner.html) or [CLI](http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests.html).

Comment: That's for error logs, I'm after test logs, will tell me the link opened, values entered, assertion passed, that sort of thing?

Comment: @Tester13 Added an Update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't actually know if SOAPUI has any kind of plugins. But you could create your own reporting structure, which would be really cool because you can customize it however you want to. In our project, we write the expected and update the actual values into the data sink and write the test status into the same, all using the groovy script :)